# Making a program that lists files in a directory and sorts the output using stat()

Tags: c

I wrote a program that uses stat() to find some details of all the files in a current directory. I then store all that information into a string using sprintf() and keep adding to the size to prevent my string from being overwritten and then I copy the string into a char**. This code seems to work but I was wondering if there is a way to make this code more efficient.

The output has to be as follows

```
-rw-rw-r-- tom users 1562 Sep 29 12:00 hello.txt
-rw-rw-r-- dick users 1024 Sep 29 12:05 igloo.txt
-rw-rw-r-- harry users 176 Sep 28 11:27 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- chaz users 2044 Sep 27 18:23 zoo.txt
```

The number after users is the file size in bytes

```
void ls_long(){
char **list = NULL;
int count = 0;
DIR *dir_ptr;
struct dirent *direntp;
char dirname[] =".";
    if(!(dir_ptr = opendir( dirname ))) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ls1: cannot open %s\n", dirname);
        return;
    }
    while((direntp = readdir(dir_ptr))){
        
        if( direntp->d_name[0] == '.' ){// check to see if name starts with a . we skip over it
            continue;
        }
        
        struct stat buf;
        char path[266];
        
        snprintf(path, 266, "%s/%s", dirname, direntp->d_name);
        if(stat(path, &buf)) {
           fprintf(stderr,"stat failed\n");
           break;
        }
        char string[600] = "";
        if(S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)){
            strcat(string, "d");//printf("d");
            
        }else{
            strcat(string, "-");//printf("-");
            
        }if( buf.st_mode & S_IRUSR )
            strcat(string, "r");
            else
                strcat(string, "-");
            if( buf.st_mode & S_IWUSR )
                strcat(string, "w");
            else
                strcat(string, "-");
            if( buf.st_mode & S_IXUSR )
                strcat(string, "x");
            else
                strcat(string, "-");
            if( buf.st_mode & S_IRGRP )
                strcat(string, "r");
            else
                strcat(string, "-");
            if( buf.st_mode & S_IWGRP )
                strcat(string, "w");
            else
                strcat(string, "-");
            if( buf.st_mode & S_IXGRP )
                strcat(string, "x");
            else
                strcat(string, "-");
            if( buf.st_mode & S_IROTH )
                strcat(string, "r");
            else
                strcat(string, "-");
            if( buf.st_mode & S_IWOTH )
                strcat(string, "w");
            else
                strcat(string, "-");
            if( buf.st_mode & S_IXOTH )
                strcat(string, "x");
            else
                strcat(string, "-");
       
        // to get user id
        struct passwd *pwd;
        if ((pwd = getpwuid(buf.st_uid)) != NULL)
            sprintf(string + strlen(string)," %s",pwd->pw_name);//printf(" %s", pwd->pw_name);
        else
            sprintf(string + strlen(string)," %d",buf.st_uid); //printf(" %d", buf.st_uid);
        
        // to get group id
        struct group *grp;
        if ((grp = getgrgid(buf.st_gid)) != NULL)
            sprintf(string + strlen(string)," %s",grp->gr_name);// printf(" %s", grp->gr_name);
        else
            sprintf(string + strlen(string)," %d",buf.st_gid);//printf(" %d", buf.st_gid);
        
        // to get file size
        sprintf(string + strlen(string)," %lld",buf.st_size);//printf(" %lld", buf.st_size);
        
        // to get date modified
        time_t t = buf.st_mtime;
        struct tm lt;
        localtime_r(&t, &lt);
        char timbuf[80];
        strftime(timbuf, sizeof(timbuf), "%b %d %X", &lt);
        sprintf(string + strlen(string)," %s",timbuf);//printf(" %s",timbuf);
        
        //print filename
        sprintf(string + strlen(string)," %s",direntp->d_name);//printf(" %s\n", path);
        
        // putting string into list so it can be sorted
        list = realloc(list, (count+1)*sizeof(*list));
        list[count] = malloc(sizeof(string));
        strcpy(list[count],string);
        count ++;
        
       // printf("%s\n",string);
    }


for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < count - i - 1; j++){
        if (strcasecmp(list[j], list[j + 1]) > 0) {
                       char* temp;
                       temp = list[j];
                       list[j] = list[j+1];
                       list[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < (count) ;i++){
    printf("%s\n",list[i]);
}
for(int i = 0;i < count;i++){
    free(list[i]);
}
closedir(dir_ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- The function is doing too much. Stick to [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle):

  - One function to iterate the directory
  - One function to collect the information about one file
  - One function to sort it
  - One function to print it
  - One function to rule them all
- `fprintf(stderr,"ls1: cannot open %s\n", dirname)` is better than nothing, but it loses an important information -- *why exactly* did `opendir` fail? Perhaps, a directory does not exist? or the user misses permissions? or something else? Use `perror` to give the important details.
- `dirent->d_name[0] == '.'` is dubious. There could be plenty of files of interest with a name starting with a dot. Why do you want to skip over them?
- `path[266]` -- What is the significance of 266? Avoid magic numbers.
- Ditto `string[600]`.
- `getpwid` and `getgrpid` may fail and return `NULL`.

= `string + strlen(string)` is an anti-pattern. As you print more and more data, and ask for the length over and over again, you are just wasting cycles. `sprintf` tells you exactly how many byte it printed. Consider something along the lines

```
    char * end = line;
    ....
        size_t bytes = sprintf(end, ....);
        end += bytes;
    ....
```

- `malloc` and `realloc` may fail. Something you should take care about.
- To sort the results, you surely want something better than bubble sort.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     char path[266];
>     
>     snprintf(path, 266, "%s/%s", dirname, direntp->d_name);
> ```

Even though these two lines are close together, it's very easy to update one and not the other.  Prefer a single constant (and better, use a provided one):

```
char path[PATH_MAX + 1]
snprintf(path, sizeof path, "%s/%s", dirname, direntp->d_name);
```

---

> ```
>     list = realloc(list, (count+1)*sizeof(*list));
> ```

This is a dangerous pattern.  If the `realloc()` fails, `list` becomes null, and we have no pointer to the memory block - it's *leaked*.  The proper pattern is:

```
void *new_mem = realloc(list, (count+1) * sizeof *list);
if (!new_mem) {
    free(list);
    goto failure_return; /* or other cleanup */
}
list = new_mem;
```

---

Repeated `strcat()` wastes processor effort - it needs to start at the beginning of the string every time.  It's more efficient if we just track the insert position ourselves.